# Каков лучший способ привязки данных к System.Windows.Forms.Charting.Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, диаграммы

У меня есть WPF форма, на которой я планирую отображать графические объекты через System.Windows.Forms.Charting.Chart.

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1">
    <dvc:Chart x:Name="MyChart"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Мне хотелось бы сделать связку отображаемых данных с элементом графика так что бы как можно меньше, а в идеале вовсе не вызывать объект MyChart при работе с данными. Данные на графике будут постоянно изменяться и обновляться.

Подскажите как бы Вы реализовали подобное ? Как я понял у объекта Chart - есть несколько способов привязки данных:

1. `MyChart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY` - но не смотря на то что там во входных параметрах IEnumerable - у меня удалось связать только с массивом типа double.
2. `MyChart.DataSource` - Тут много [способ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.datasource?view=netframework-4.7.2) связки данных - мне приглянулcя интерфейс IDataSource - однако не охото подключать System.Web.dll к проекту только из за одного интерфейса... Да и с таблицами не очень хочется возиться.

Как на Ваш взгляд лучше всего подобную связку сделать ?С№

Answer (score 0):

В общем я пока что вот такой класс прослойку сделал, который помогает оперировать с графиком через DataTable без какого либо взаимодействия с объектом Chart прямую. Если у кого нибудь будет более интересное / превильное решение то подскажите плиз.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Data;

using Color = System.Drawing.Color;
using Point = System.Drawing.Point;
using ToolTip = System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip;

namespace ChartTest
{
    public class ChartKeeper
{
    public ChartKeeper(Chart chart, bool use_legend = true, bool use_grid = false, bool use_tooltip = true)
    {
        this.chart = chart ?? throw new ArgumentException("Chart is null");

        chart.Series.Clear();
        chart.ChartAreas.Clear();
        chart.Legends.Clear();

        chart.DataSource = Data;
        chart.ChartAreas.Add("DefaultArea");
        if (use_legend)
            chart.Legends.Add("DefaultLegend");

        if (!use_grid)
        {
            chart.ChartAreas["DefaultArea"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
            chart.ChartAreas["DefaultArea"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        }

        this.use_tooltip = use_tooltip;

        Subscribe_events();
    }

    ~ChartKeeper()
    {
        Unsubscribe_events();
    }

    private readonly bool use_tooltip;
    private readonly Chart chart;
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> x_y_comparer = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    public DataTable Data { get; } = new DataTable();
    private Point? prevPosition = null;
    ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();

    public void Subscribe_events()
    {
        Data.TableNewRow += Table_TableNewRow;
        Data.TableCleared += Table_TableCleared;
        Data.ColumnChanged += Table_ColumnChanged;
        Data.RowChanged += Table_RowChanged;
        Data.RowDeleted += Table_RowDeleted;
        Data.Columns.CollectionChanged += Columns_CollectionChanged;

        if (use_tooltip)
        {
            chart.MouseMove += Chart_MouseMove;
            chart.MouseLeave += Chart_MouseLeave;
        }
    }

    public void Unsubscribe_events()
    {
        Data.TableNewRow -= Table_TableNewRow;
        Data.TableCleared -= Table_TableCleared;
        Data.ColumnChanged -= Table_ColumnChanged;
        Data.RowChanged -= Table_RowChanged;
        Data.RowDeleted -= Table_RowDeleted;
        Data.Columns.CollectionChanged -= Columns_CollectionChanged;

        if (use_tooltip)
        {
            chart.MouseMove -= Chart_MouseMove;
            chart.MouseLeave -= Chart_MouseLeave;
        }
    }

    private void Chart_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tooltip.Hide(chart);
    }

    private void Table_RowDeleted(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        chart.DataBind();
    }

    private void Table_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        chart.DataBind();
    }

    private void Table_ColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        chart.DataBind();
    }

    private void Table_TableCleared(object sender, DataTableClearEventArgs e)
    {
        chart.DataBind();
    }

    private void Table_TableNewRow(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        chart.DataBind();
    }

    private bool is_removing = false;
    private bool is_x_removing = false;
    private void Columns_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Element is DataColumn col)
        {
            if (!Data.Columns.Contains(col.ColumnName))
            {
                if (!is_removing)
                {
                    bool is_x = chart.Series.Any(x => x.XValueMember == col.ColumnName);

                    if (is_x)
                    {
                        List<string> serias_names = new List<string>(x_y_comparer[col.ColumnName]);
                        is_x_removing = true;
                        foreach (var item in serias_names)
                        {
                            Data.Columns.Remove(Data.Columns[item]); // Удаляем колонку с Y тем самым вызываем рекурсию
                        }
                        is_x_removing = false;
                    }
                    else // if Y
                    {
                        List<string> serias_names = new List<string>(chart.Series.Where(y => y.YValueMembers == col.ColumnName).Select(x => x.Name));
                        foreach (var item in serias_names)
                        {
                            RemoveLine(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!is_x_removing)
            chart.DataBind();
    }

    public void AddLine(string line_name, string x_name, string y_name, Color color, SeriesChartType type, int width)
    {
        if (!chart.Series.Any(x => x.Name == line_name))
        {
            if (x_y_comparer.ContainsKey(x_name))
            {
                x_y_comparer[x_name].Add(y_name);
            }
            else
            {
                x_y_comparer.Add(x_name, new List<string> { y_name });
            }

            if (!Data.Columns.Contains(x_name))
                Data.Columns.Add(x_name);
            if (!Data.Columns.Contains(y_name))
                Data.Columns.Add(y_name);

            chart.Series.Add(line_name);
            chart.Series[line_name].XValueMember = x_name;
            chart.Series[line_name].YValueMembers = y_name;
            chart.Series[line_name].ChartType = type;
            chart.Series[line_name].ChartArea = "DefaultArea";
            chart.Series[line_name].Name = line_name;
            chart.Series[line_name].Color = color;
            chart.Series[line_name].BorderWidth = width;

            chart.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Chart already contains line with name " + line_name);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveLine(string name)
    {
        is_removing = true;
        string x_name = chart.Series[name].XValueMember;
        string y_name = chart.Series[name].YValueMembers;

        chart.Series.RemoveAt(chart.Series.IndexOf(name));

        if (x_y_comparer[x_name].Count > 1)
        {
            x_y_comparer[x_name].Remove(y_name);
        }
        else
        {
            x_y_comparer.Remove(x_name);
            if (Data.Columns.Contains(x_name))
                Data.Columns.Remove(x_name);
        }

        if (!x_y_comparer.Values.Any(x => x.Contains(y_name)) && Data.Columns.Contains(y_name))
            Data.Columns.Remove(y_name);
        is_removing = false;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        chart.Update();
    }

    private void Chart_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = e.Location;
        if (prevPosition.HasValue && pos == prevPosition.Value)
            return;

        prevPosition = pos;
        var results = chart.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false, ChartElementType.DataPoint); // set ChartElementType.PlottingArea for full area, not only DataPoints
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint) // set ChartElementType.PlottingArea for full area, not only DataPoints
            {
                result.ChartArea.CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(pos, true);
                result.ChartArea.CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(pos, true);

                int pX = (int)result.ChartArea.CursorX.Position - 1; //X Axis Coordinate of your mouse cursor

                string x_name = result.Series.XValueMember;
                string y_name = result.Series.YValueMembers;

                var yVal = Data.Rows[pX][y_name];
                var xVal = Data.Rows[pX][x_name];
                tooltip.Show(string.Format("{0} : X={1} Y={2}", result.Series.Name, xVal, yVal), chart, pos.X, pos.Y - 15);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```